# How to get year from number of day's in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
select
  datediff('year',CURRENT_DATE,birthday) as user_age
from user_table limit 20
```

I tried using the code above, but it gives me the error below. That it only takes two dates, and I don't want to divide by 365. Is there another function I can use.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [date_part](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#date_part) to get the years of the two dates and then substract them:

```sql
select date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) - date_part('year', birthday) from user_table
```

This approach is prone to [off-by-one errors](https://xkcd.com/2248/).

To get around of this error, you also have to take the day and month into account:

```sql
select 
  birthday,
  date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) - date_part('year', birthday) +
    if((date_part('month', CURRENT_DATE) - date_part('month', birthday)) * 100 + 
        date_part('day', CURRENT_DATE) - date_part('day', birthday)  < 0, -1, 0)
  as age
from user_table
```

Comment: is there a way still do the above calculation and not make off-by-one errors.

Comment: yes, I have added a fix